# check if any select box has changed after button click

Tags: jquery

I want to check a group of select boxes and see if they changed after a button has clicked.

```
<select name="data[model][that]" class="location_dropdown">
    <option value="value1">value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">value 2</option>
    <option value="value3" selected="selected">value 3</option>
</select>

<select name="data[model][that]" class="location_dropdown">
    <option value="value1">value 1</option>
    <option value="value2" selected="selected">value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">value 3</option>
</select>

<select name="data[model][other]" class="location_dropdown">
    <option value="value1" selected="selected">value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">value 3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#update-selected-btn').click(function(){
        $('.location_dropdown').each(function(){



        });
    });

    if state hasnt changed on any drop downs alert("nothing selected")

});
```

Obviously cant use onchange as I want to check for change when button click triggered. I was thinking about maybe building a array of values and checking them against each other, but wonder if there is another solution.

**UPDATE:**

I did attempt this, but syntax isnt right.

```
$('.location_dropdown').each(function(){
    if ($(this + " option:selected").prop('selected') == 'selected'){
       changed++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a global variable, when something is selected just add a data attribute to the select and in your button click look for the dropdown with the attributes.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wUb96/)

```
     $('#update-selected-btn').click(function(){
        var selected = $('.location_dropdown[data-changed]'); //select the changed ones
        if(selected .length == 0)
        {
           alert('nothing selected'); return
        }
        selected .each(function(){
             //do something with them.
        });
    });

    $('.location_dropdown').change(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-changed', 'true'); //Add attribute to the selected ones.
    });
```

Comment: Started to do this: 
    $(document).on('change', '#data1', function(e) {
        alert($('#data1').val());
    });

    $("select").each(function( index ) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
but pscoder method is better!

Comment: @TheTechy id you want to remove the attribute after processing you can just do selected.removeAttr('data-changed');

Answer (score 4):

You can use a global variable to monitor the change in selection of selects.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dF4HD/)**

```
var dropdownChanged = false;
$('.location_dropdown').change(function(){    
     dropdownChanged = true;    
});


$('#update-selected-btn').click(function(){
    dropdownChanged = false;
});
```

Comment: If the value changes and then changes into its first value again your code doesn't work.